# Error in nonlinear least square fit of sine function with exponential decay

Tags: python, lmfit

My nonlinear data are approximated using a least square fit with the formula `Asin(wt+phase)exp(-decay*t)` while keeping `omega(w)` as a constant. I have tried several approaches without success.

Below is my code

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import loadtxt
import lmfit
np.random.seed(2)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)
decay = 4.5
shift = 0
amp = 0.0015
y = amp * np.sin(x*5+shift) * np.exp(-x*decay)
yn = y + np.random.normal(size=y.size, scale=0.450)


def resid(params, x, ydata):
    decay = params['decay'].value
    shift = params['shift'].value
    amp = params['amp'].value

    y_model = amp * np.sin(x*5+shift) * np.exp(-x*decay)
    return y_model - ydata
params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('shift', 0.0, min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
params.add('amp', 0.0015, min=0, max=0.02)
params.add('decay', 4.0, min=0, max=10.0)
fit = lmfit.minimize(resid, params, args=(x, yn), method='differential_evolution')
print("\n\n# Fit using differential_evolution:")
lmfit.report_fit(fit)
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, yn+fit.residual, 'b--', lw=2)
plt.legend(['data', 'leastsq', 'diffev'], loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please read up on how to create an MCVE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
We like to help here on Stackoverflow but most of us don't have much time to help. With an MCVE you make it easy for us to reproduce your issues so we can spend more time focusing on the actual issue you have.

Comment: Please provide exact input, and exact expected output. Also link to the theory.

Comment: Looking at your data: Your decay is massive in comparison to the amplitude, leading to problems of small values. You have about 10 data points that behave like your expected formula but 90 points that are basically zero - and on top of it you mask these values with random noise. Your approach works as is well for smaller decay values and larger amp values.

Answer (score 0):

Comments pointed out that the decay you have is very severe.  But also, the noise you add to `yn` is enormous compared to your decaying sine wave.   You and others may have missed this because you do not plot the `yn` array that you fit, rather you plot `y`,  without the added noise `data`.

If you do plot the data you actually use in the fit:

```
plt.plot(x, yn, 'ko', lw=2)
plt.show()
```

you will see this:

[image]

You also label the very poort best-fit you get as `leastsq` though you actually used `differential_evolution`.

If you lower the noise and the decay in your test data, and really fit with `leastsq`, you might have something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import lmfit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(2)
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

decay = 0.6
shift = 0
amp = 0.025
y = amp * np.sin(x*5+shift) * np.exp(-x*decay)
yn = y + np.random.normal(size=y.size, scale=0.001)

def resid(params, x, ydata):
    decay = params['decay'].value
    shift = params['shift'].value
    amp = params['amp'].value

    y_model = amp * np.sin(x*5+shift) * np.exp(-x*decay)
    return y_model - ydata

params = lmfit.Parameters()
params.add('shift', 0.0, min=-np.pi, max=np.pi)
params.add('amp', 0.01)
params.add('decay', 0.2, min=0, max=50)
fit = lmfit.minimize(resid, params, args=(x, yn))


print("\n\n# Fit using differential_evolution:")
lmfit.report_fit(fit)
plt.plot(x, yn, 'ko', lw=2)
plt.plot(x, yn+fit.residual, 'b--', lw=2)
plt.legend(['data', 'leastsq'], loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

which will give a report of

```
# Fit using differential_evolution:
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 21
    # data points      = 101
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 1.0894e-04
    reduced chi-square = 1.1117e-06
    Akaike info crit   = -1381.71974
    Bayesian info crit = -1373.87437
[[Variables]]
    shift:  0.00796328 +/- 0.01999031 (251.03%) (init = 0)
    amp:    0.02448871 +/- 7.5756e-04 (3.09%) (init = 0.01)
    decay:  0.59826922 +/- 0.02587107 (4.32%) (init = 0.2)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(amp, decay)   =  0.725
    C(shift, amp)   = -0.147
    C(shift, decay) = -0.105
```

and a plot of[image]

I think the conclusion is that your residual function and setting up the problem are OK, but your very noisy test data set is not represented by that decaying sine-wave very well.